# What does the "__LINKEDIT segment does not cover the end of the file" mean?

Tags: python, macos, bundle, cx-freeze

What does the `__LINKEDIT segment does not cover the end of the file` mean?

I am currently bundling an application on OSX and keep running into this error when actioning my python application which has been built using CX_Freeze.

I am also getting this error when trying to codesign the application.

Comment: For reference this is the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/48336883/5329717