# codesign an old Director projector on OS X 10.13 - perhaps manipulate __LINKEDIT segment value

Tags: macos, codesign, mach-o, adobe-director

(See Updates at end of this post)

For $reasons, I need to codesign an old Director projector that we can no longer re-publish (no access to original source code or to Director).

I'm doing this because when run without being signed, the app now opens a Finder window with a prompt saying *"Where is..."* asking for a file that's one of the embedded projector resources.

But... If I `cd` into the `Projector.app` contents (it's not really called that, but you get the idea) and find the projector binary inside `Contents/MacOS/` and run this binary from terminal, the app launches and runs fine, once it's decompressed the (presumably) attached archive at the end of the binary...

```
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.30.2/Common/ChunkCompression.cpp:50: Error: unsupported compressor 8
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.30.2/Libraries/CompressData/CompressData.c:353: Error: Unknown compression scheme encountered for file '/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/Exceptions.plist'
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.30.2/Common/ChunkCompression.cpp:50: Error: unsupported compressor 8
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.30.2/Libraries/CompressData/CompressData.c:353: Error: Unknown compression scheme encountered for file '/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Library/AppExceptions.bundle/Exceptions.plist'
271 blocks
1120 blocks
274 blocks
136 blocks
255 blocks
120 blocks
1487 blocks
575 blocks
1128 blocks
570 blocks
104 blocks
2042 blocks
4889 blocks
677 blocks
388 blocks
363 blocks
700 blocks
23010 blocks

...app opens and runs correctly at this point
```

I can't ask our users to do this (they're very non-technical) so I'm guessing that the *"Where is..."* prompt is some aspect of the OS X Gatekeeper, and hence I'm hoping that signing the binary will make it click-runnable again.

When I try and codesign the binary `App.app/Contents/MacOS/projector` I get:

```
main executable failed strict validation
```

Setting the `--no-strict` codesign option gives a bit more detail:

```
the __LINKEDIT segment does not cover the end of the file (can't be processed)
```

Which I think is because the Director projector is a binary with a bundled archive containing the rest of the application's resources, appended to the end of the executable. Some [googling shows](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=__LINKEDIT%20segment%20does%20not%20cover%20the%20end%20of%20the%20file) that other projects have similar problems with their embedded resources.

I've tried using [macho_edit](https://github.com/Tyilo/macho_edit) to see if I could modify the binary, but with no joy. I've also tried signing using [jtool](http://newosxbook.com/tools/jtool.html#sign), but again, this didn't work.

So now, opening the binary in [MachOView](https://github.com/gdbinit/MachOView):

[image: MachOView of binary]

I'm hoping that I can hexedit the binary and change the value of the `__LINKEDIT segment` so it covers the end of the file, and hence so the codesigning will work, but I have no idea what the modified value should be, or what else if anything I need to change. Any tips appreciated.

**Update 1** - in response to [Kamil.S's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48336883/391826)

I've tried adjusting the `File Size` value in __LINKEDIT segment, so this + the `File Offset` is the same as the actual binary (I tried a few times; you actually need to change the `VM Size` to be the same value as the `File Size` or you get `Killed: 9` by the OS. Same happens if you set `File Size` to be the total size of the binary), but with no luck. With the new `File Size` and `VM Size` values, I can still run the binary, but I can't codesign it; I do however, **get a slightly different error message**:

```
file not in an order that can be processed (link edit information does not fill the __LINKEDIT segment)
```

**Update 2** - https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-OSX-Code-Signing#pyinstaller-fix-implementation has a bit more detail on the same problem:

> PyInstaller breaks OSX code signing because it appends python code at
>   the end of the binary. Appending data at the end of executable breaks
>   the Mach-o format structure. `codesign` utility complains with the
>   following messages.
>
> ```
> the __LINKEDIT segment does not cover the end of the file (can't be processed)
>
> file not in an order that can be processed (link edit information does not fill the __LINKEDIT segment)
> ```
>
> - Fix __LINKEDIT - File Size (offset + File size == exe size), VM Size- same as 'File Size'
> - Fix LC_SYMTAB - String Table Size - last data in mach-o file (offset + size = exe size on the filesystem) - The data appended to the executable will be part of the 'String Table' (Last data section in
>     Mach-O file).

I'll take a look at fixing `LC_SYMTAB` to see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__LINKEDIT`'s `File Offset` + `File Size` should be equal to physical executable size. You can tinker with `File Size` in `MachOView` by double clicking the value, editing it and saving - the executable should be fine. Just don't touch `File Offset` because this will definitely break it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've updated my question after trying to adjust the `File Size` using MachOView. Still can't codesign, but now am getting a slightly different error which might help: `file not in an order that can be processed (link edit information does not fill the __LINKEDIT segment)`

Comment: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-OSX-Code-Signing#pyinstaller-fix-implementation looks like it has a bit more detail on the same problem

Comment: Since your app  is MacOS 10.4 it's pre `LC_DYLD_INFO` & `LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY` days as described here for 10.5 & 10.6 http://www.newosxbook.com/articles/DYLD.html . Current `Mach-O` loading makes `LC_SYMTAB` obligatory if the executable hasn't got `LC_DYLD*` , but I'm not sure how it's exactly resolved by `DYLD`. `__LINKEDIT` is basically `DYLD`'s segment.

Comment: Brilliant, that was it. Thanks Kamil - needed to adjust __LINKEDIT as per your suggestion and also LC_SYMTAB as per https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-OSX-Code-Signing#pyinstaller-fix-implementation

Answer (score 1):

If the app can't find its external resources when being run normally from the Finder, that sounds like a result of [Gatekeeper Path Randomization](https://mjtsai.com/blog/2016/06/16/gatekeeper-path-randomization/). The OS moves the app to a hidden read-only location when it's run, and it can't find the resources.

I don't think that signing the app binary itself will fix this problem and prevent the OS from doing path randomization. The user either needs to move the application to a different directory after extracting it, or you need to distribute the application inside a disk image that has been signed with your Developer ID certificate. DropDMG (linked from the post above) can create signed disk images, that might be worth a quick try.

Comment: Thanks for those links. DropDMG is https://c-command.com/dropdmg/ for any future comment readers. I made a signed .dmg, but this still results in the "Where is..." prompt. Also, part of the app's features need r/w access, which wouldn't work when running from the .dmg anyway, so users would still need to drag the app to the /Applications to run.

Answer (score 1):

DIrector uses a scheme widely used on Windows called "Overload". I attaches some data at the end of the physical file, but beyond the size of the executable image.
This approach is not supported with Mach-O files. The physical image has to end with the last byte covered by the LINKEDIT segment, and even the order of items inside the LINKEDIT segment is well defined. Reason for this was prebinding in the past, now it is codesigning.

The appended data is the initial DIR/DXR Directory wants to load first. I guess this has been fixed later by adding the DIR/DXR into the application bundle. But I am not anymore into Director, so I am not sure about this.