# Python executable in Swift macOS app cannot archive

Tags: python, swift, xcode

I have a macOS app that facilitate automatic wifi authentication. When I'm trying to validate the app (in the Xcode archive manager), it reports

> Couldn't find platform family in Info.plist CFBundleSupportedPlatforms
>   or Mach-O LC_VERSION_MIN for .Python

The app itself works like a charm. But I'm trying to validate it so it doesn't show up as 'Unidentified developer' when other people get my app. I have recently I used Pyinstaller to create a unix executable that handles automatic wifi authentication. After checking the logs, it is apparent that something within the `.Python` folder inside the "auth" folder generated by Pyinstaller.

My app is here: https://github.com/Clumsyndicate/AutoAuth

I have tried the solutions presented in [Couldn't find platform family in Info.plist CFBundleSupportedPlatforms or Mach-O LC_VERSION_MIN for phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529583/couldnt-find-platform-family-in-info-plist-cfbundlesupportedplatforms-or-mach-o), and it did not work for me.

I have tried:

1. Remove all DSYM files (I have no DSYM files)
2. Add "MacOSX" to "CFBundleSupportedPlatforms" in info.plist

I checked out the logs and found the relevant section of '.Python'.

`2018-11-24 15:33:48 +0000  [OPTIONAL] Didn't find info dictionary for <DVTFilePath:0x7ff4a37ee7e0:'/Users/johnsonzhou/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2018-11-24/NewAuto 24-11-2018, 23.32.xcarchive/Products/Applications/NewAuto.app/Contents/Resources/auth/.Python'>: Error Domain=DVTFoundationNSBundleAdditionsErrorDomain Code=1 "Couldn't load Info dictionary for <DVTFilePath:0x7ff4a37ee7e0:'/Users/johnsonzhou/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2018-11-24/NewAuto 24-11-2018, 23.32.xcarchive/Products/Applications/NewAuto.app/Contents/Resources/auth/.Python'>" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Couldn't load Info dictionary for <DVTFilePath:0x7ff4a37ee7e0:'/Users/johnsonzhou/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2018-11-24/NewAuto 24-11-2018, 23.32.xcarchive/Products/Applications/NewAuto.app/Contents/Resources/auth/.Python'>}`

I'm a stack overflow, macOS dev. and python noob. Please correct me if I made any mistakes. Any help counts!

Comment: Can you provide `MachOView` output of your executable as in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48324224/codesign-an-old-director-projector-on-os-x-10-13-perhaps-manipulate-linkedit/48336883#48336883 ?