# Py2App Fails MacOS Signing on liblzma.5.dylib

Tags: python, macos, code-signing, py2app

I have been upgrading a project from Python2.7  to Python3.8 while at the same time dealing with deployment/signing issues on MacOS Mojave and Catalina.

The Python app is build using Py2app and then signed, but exactly one file is failing when signing:

```
codesign --sign "${IDENTITY}"  --entitlements ../entitleme.plist  --deep "demo.app/"          --force    --options runtime
demo.app/: main executable failed strict validation
In subcomponent: /demo.app/Contents/Frameworks/liblzma.5.dylib
```

and without strict:

```
codesign --sign "${IDENTITY}" --entitlements ../entitleme.plist  --deep "demo.app/" --no-strict --force  --options runtime
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate: the __LINKEDIT segment does not cover the end of the file (can't be processed) in: demo.app/Contents/Frameworks/liblzma.5.dylib
demo.app/: the codesign_allocate helper tool cannot be found or used
In subcomponent: demo.app/Contents/Frameworks/liblzma.5.dylib
```

Another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48324224/codesign-an-old-director-projector-on-os-x-10-13-perhaps-manipulate-linkedit/48336883#48336883)  indicated that PyInstaller or other systems had similar problems and that this [incomplete solution](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-OSX-Code-Signing#pyinstaller-fix-implementation) fixed it. However, the actual solution (if found) appears uninteligible in the edits or in changes to the linked material. Also, I note that `codesign_allocate` is listed as not found but it is in the path and runs fine, so I suspect its usage on a file with the `__LINKEDIT` segment error is bad.

It appears that the liblzma comes from compressed algorithms incorporated by a library during the py2app build, and attempts to pursue an update have thusfar been unfruitful---though I have begun to wonder whether recompiling the source material on the latest MacOS will correct these errors.

Is there a known path for resolving this issue?

Comment: FWIW, lzma is part of the python standard library now, and so is included with a standard python interpreter.  If you're using conda, the library comes from the 'xz' package.  Here is conda-forge's recipe for building it, in case that's interesting: https://github.com/conda-forge/xz-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/meta.yaml

Comment: How did you install your python interpreter?  If you didn't get it from conda, maybe try that?  If you did, maybe try conda-forge instead of the defaults channel, or vice-versa.  Hopefully SOMEBODY is building liblzma correctly.  And if it's a problem no matter where your python interpreter comes from, then perhaps it's a bug in the liblzma Makefile itself, and so should be reported upstream.  (Let's hope that's not it.)

Comment: @stuartberg This is right on with my findings so far. I am using pyenv and I am not sure of the source, but found that the py2app build is using TWO copies of the library on from `/usr/local/opt/xz/lib/liblzma.5.dylib `, on from `~/pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/liblzma.5.dylib`  the local xz verion is 8.5.0 from brew and does not sign while the python3.8  while the other does sign and is version 8.4.0. I copied over the 8.5.0 and it works. Also, I could not uninstall xz as it is a dependency of other important things.  I'm troubled on while py2app prefers this.

Comment: FWIW, apparently xz-5.2.4 ships with liblzma.dylib 8.4.0, and xz-5.2.5 uses 8.5.0.  But it's hard to know if the difference is due to the version, or the different distrbutions being used (brew vs. the PIL packagers).  The fact that two exist in your setup is a consequence of the Python "wheel" format requiring each package to supply its own dylibs.  If you're able to create a conda environment for your app, I think it's worth trying.  Especially if you can install your dependencies from conda-forge.

Answer (score 1):

So I had a similar issue on Github Actions build.
I searched and found there is a .dylib located at (I ran a 40 min find command to locate this):

```
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.5/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/liblzma.5.dylib
```

Your path will change depending on the version of Python.

I then copied this dylib over in to the .app file:

```
cp /System/Volumes/Data/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.5/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/liblzma.5.dylib APPNAME.app/Contents/Frameworks/liblzma.5.dylib
```

That made the sign finish successfully.

Thanks @Steve in the comments to the question that pointed this is the solution direction.

Answer (score 1):

Update for later version:

Update for:

- python 3.10.6
- pyenv 2.3.4
- OS X 12.5.1,
- py2app 2.8.2
- homebrew 3.6.0

With the virutal environment installed at

PROJECT_VENV=~/PycharmProjects/PyUt/pyenv-3.10.6

copying this file fixes the same problem

cp /opt/homebrew/opt/xz/lib/liblzma.5.dylib ${PROJECT_VENV}/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs

Fixes the problem

For me these are depending on the current version of HOMEBREW and the virtual environment